# Integration testing with maven: run jar before tests and terminate after

Tags: java, maven, testing, integration-testing

I have a runnable jar that I want to run in a new process before my integration test start (on `pre-integration-test`) and get it terminated after my integration tests finish (on `post-integration-test`).

One of the things I could use is [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) or [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) to start new process on `pre-integration-test` but how do I terminate it?

Maybe there is a better solution for what I am trying to achieve?

PS: I build my project both on Windows and Linux, so portability matters for me.

Comment: use failsafe, the shaded jar will run in its jvm, after the tests finish failsafe will shutdown that jvm

Comment: @guido not really sure that I understand your suggestion. How do I use failsafe to sun something?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [maven-process-plugin](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/maven-process-plugin) open sourced by BV to start and stop any process in pre and post-integration phase respectively. There is an example in the readme that does exactly what you want (start a runnable jar). Hope that helps.

The main idea is to write a maven plugin with two goals - start, and stop. Start runs in your pre-integration-phase and runs any process you would like to run. Java's process builder can be used to start processes like running jars, etc. Store the started Process in a datastructure such as a Map or a Stack. 'Stop' will stop all the processes it has started. Since this is such a generic problem, I would recommend the above plugin for starting and stopping any processes easily for your integration tests. Simply add the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
        <executions>
            <!--Start process-->
            <execution>
                <id>start-jar</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals><goal>start</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDir>app</workingDir>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>java</argument>
                        <argument>-jar</argument>
                        <argument>app.jar</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!--Stop Process-->
            <execution>
                <id>stop-jar-process</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals><goal>stop-all</goal></goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: bazaarvoice/process-exec-maven-plugin seems quite dead, a successor seems to be https://github.com/chonton/process-exec-maven-plugin

Comment: @MarkusSchulte that plugin sadly doesn't work at all either. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked with *exec* goal from exec-maven-plugin and *async* setting.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>Start your java process</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <async>true</async>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <classpath/><!-- classpath from the module dependencies-->
        <argument>your.MainClass</argument>
      </arguments>
      <environmentVariables>
        <somevariable>isSet</someVariable>
      </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The process gets automatically killed as soon as the maven run is over. You may also want to look at the *asyncDestroyOnShutdown* option

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using maven-antrun-plugin.

If your background process is java process you can use the java ant target and give it a stop timeout. If you know that your integration tests will get over say after N seconds, fork & spawn the process and stop the process after a timeout (N)

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-my-Application</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <java jar="target/myapp-${project.version}.jar"
                                  spawn="true"
                                  fork="true"
                                  timeout="120">
                                <sysproperty key="env" value="test" />
                                <arg value="--xyz" /> <arg value="123" />
                            </java>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was Linux only, I'd write the PID to a file and then just kill the process using this PID later.

My guess is that you can achieve something similar on Windows but you'd need a couple of non-standard tools.

The alternative is to open a socket in the new process and listen for a kill command on this socket. That works on all platforms but you need to modify the JAR.

Note: If you need to run several the integration tests in parallel, this will also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to include some kind of stop mechanism in your external jar (compare to the stop port of tomcat).

That way you would not need to handle PIDs or anything.

The easiest, and most resource saving way would be to simply open a server socket on a predefined (overridable) port.

Answer (score 0):

Kill it by using call bash

```
 <!--Kill the started process.-->
          <target>
            <exec executable="bash"
                  dir="${project.build.directory}"
                  spawn="false">
              <arg value="-c"/>
              <arg value="ps ax | grep -i '${project.artifactId}' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGTERM"/>
            </exec>
          </target>
```

Comment: Why would you pipe output of `ps` through `grep` and `awk` (which can certainly do the `grep` bit) to feed `kill` instead of using `pkill`?

Comment: @OndrejK.maybe because I am not knowing that perhaps you have a better version of it?

Comment: [`pkill`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html) as mentioned.