# Maven build - run an application then perform JUnit tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing, testing, junit, pom.xml

As part of my build process, I would like maven to start a program and then execute JUNIT tests in the same phase, which is the mvn test phase.

I am using Spring Boot as well as the Spring Boot Maven plugin. As you know Spring boot has an embedded tomcat container. So I can just run my application on this tomcat server by just running as an application in eclipse.

For example when I run `mvn test`, I would like my application to run FIRST and then have the tests executed.

I have seen the exec-maven plugin being used and that you specify the phase in the maven build cycle that you want the application to run. The earliest phase that it allows you to specify is the test phase.

**But I'm not sure if the Application will run immediately before the tests?**

**How do I specify in my POM file that I want the application to run BEFORE the test phase?**

Comment: You seem to be describing a desire to do end-to-end testing (a kind of integration test) against your application, while Maven's test phase is geared towards running your unit tests (not all tests bootstrapped via JUnit are unit tests). Suggest you take a look at configuring your build to instead run "mvn verify" and plan to execute your tests in the integration-test phase.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want, to do integration testing.

Comment: Use the maven-failsafe-plugin to integrate integration-tests in your maven build.

Comment: Looks like this is not a separate question but clarification of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31714518/1240557 ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131747/integration-testing-with-maven-run-jar-before-tests-and-terminate-after

Comment: Yes, I probably should have mentioned the maven failsafe plugin. By default it wants your test classes to be named such that they end in "IT" rather than "Test". It's not too difficult to integrate into your maven build.